# [Keras][Embedding] How do I expand the vocabulary size of a pre trained embedding

Tags: python, keras, nlp, embedding

I have a pre-trained Keras model and there's a word embedding [1000 vocabulary * 200 dimensions] inside of the model.

Now I want to load it back to memory and continuous training it with new data. The vocabulary size increased because of the new data.

I am wondering if it's possible to replace this embedding with a bigger vocabulary size [2000 vocabulary * 200 dimensions] but keeping other parameter weights unchanged for the entire model.

Comment: You can set `trainable = True` in your `embedding layer`. This would train the weights for unseen words and update/finetune vectors of the existing words in the vocabulary. But this wont save the altered embeddings to your memory separately.

Comment: I am wondering how I can change the embedding dimension from [1000 * 200] to [2000 * 200] while keeping all other parameters within the network [like other dense layers] the same by only replacing the embedding.

Comment: What pretrained model do you have?? The change from `1000` to `2000` you are referring here is a change in size of vocab which should be solved by what i suggested if you are using `word-embeddings`. However if you have a pretrained model like `BERT` or something you will have to do much more. Which one is it??

Comment: Maybe a combination of `get_weights` and `set_weights` (along with a concatenation operation) could do the job? (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#get_weights and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#set_weights)